# php - mysql database insert null vs 0

Tags: php, mysql

Newbie php programmer for my non-profit

I have a form which inserts data from our librarian to enter a new book.

Everything works when entering a new book except for this.

when I go to validate, php server-side 
this code is included in my validation function.

```
$YearPub = (int)$_POST['YearPub'];
```

The value from the form is null (`$_post['['YearPub']`)

but the above statement returns a `0` (zero value) for `$YearPub`

Why?

spent hours on this today.
thanks for help
claudia

Comment: The `(int)` cast forces it to convert the value to a number. Don't do that if you want to keep the original value.'

Answer (score 1):

This is because your null value is cast to `int`.

You can make simple test `echo (int)null;` to see it on your own.

[Here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.casting) you can read more about casting to int.